# Define colors in a central file and import them to other tex documents

Tags: color, include

I'm new to LaTeX, so this might be a stupid question, but is there a way how I can define colors in one file and then use them by their name in another document? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
% myColorFile
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{29, 66, 129}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

and in the main file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\include{myColorFile}
\begin{document}
    % mycolor from myColorFile
    \textcolor{mycolor}{Some colored text}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put

```
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{29, 66, 129}% RGB not rgb, rgb is 0-1 range
\definecolor{myzzz}{rgb}{0, .5, .7}
%....
```

in `mycolors.sty`

then use

```
 \usepackage{mycolors}
```

in any document where you want these colours.

Comment: Where do I save `mycolors.sty` to on Windows? I'm using the MikTex distribution

Comment: simplest is to put it in the folder with your document then it will work, to save copying it when you want a new document you will be able to put it in the default search path, in texlive that would  be %HOME%/texmf/tex/latex, miktex will have a similar default but I'm not sure which, some miktex user will comment here probably. But you can test the file with it in the document folder first.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I needed to follow these steps: https://miktex.org/faq/local-additions and then register this path through the MikTex Console: `%USERPROFILE%\Roaming\MiKTeX\mytexmf`. Just putting the `*.sty` file in the same directory as the actual main document worked as well.